# Erro ao ler CSV: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, csv

Estou tentando pegar 3 valores diferentes de 3 arquivo csv distintos e multiplicá-los, mas está dando este erro. Onde errei? Ou o que falta acrescentar?!

**Erro:**

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Acessando arquivos CSV\fgetcsv.php on line 34
>
> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Acessando arquivos CSV\fgetcsv.php on line 34

**Código:**

```
<?php
$file1 = __DIR__ . '/Trabalhos.csv';
$csv1 = file($file1);
foreach ($csv1 as $row1 => $line1) {
    $row1++;
    $column1 = str_getcsv($line1, ';');
    if ($row1 == 2) {
        echo $column1[6]."<br>";
        $valor1 = $column1[6];
    }
}

$file2 = __DIR__ . '/produtividade do trabalho.csv';
$csv2 = file($file2);
foreach ($csv2 as $row2 => $line2) {
    $row2++;
    $column2 = str_getcsv($line2, ';');
    if ($row2 == 2) {
        echo $column2[9]."<br>";
        $valor2 = $column2[9];
    }
}
$file3 = __DIR__ . '/inatividade do trabalho.csv';
$csv3 = file($file3);
foreach ($csv3 as $row3 => $line3) {
    $row3++;
    $column3 = str_getcsv($line3, ';');
    if ($row3 == 2) {
        echo $column3[0]."<br>";
        $valor3 = $column3[0];
    }
}

$total = $valor1 * $valor2 * $valor3

?>
```

Comment: Copia o erro ao invés de postar foto.

Comment: Perdão. Vou colocar.

Comment: Testei o teu PHP e esta perfeito, o problema é no CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é no conteúdo de um dos CSVs, não tem como saber, mas o problema é que ao pegar o valor como em:

```
 echo $column2[9]."<br>";
```

Deve estar pegando o item errado em um deles, então ao tentar multiplicar:

```
 $total = $valor1 * $valor2 * $valor3;
```

Deve estar ocasionando o erro, veja se fizer isto irá obter o erro:

```
<?php

$valor1 = 'foo';
$valor2 = '2';
$valor3 = '3';

$total = $valor1 * $valor2 * $valor3;
```

Ou seja a mensagem indica que você esta tentando fazer uma operação matemática sem ter um numero valido:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

É importante entender que formatos com `,` em números não são considerados números para operações matemáticas, então se receber algo como:

> 1.074,00

Isto não será um numero "valido", então basta tratar, segue o código revisado (para simplificar e evitar repetição de códigos movi para uma função)

```
<?php

function pegar_valor_coluna($arquivo, $getrow, $getcol)
{
    $csv = file($arquivo);
    $row = 0;

    foreach ($csv as $row => $line) {
        $row++;

        if ($row == $getrow) {
            $column = str_getcsv($line, ';');
            $valor = $column[$getcol];

            //Conversão para números simples

            //Conversão para números simples
            $valor = str_replace(array('.', ' '), '', $valor);
            $valor = str_replace(',', '', $valor);

            return $valor;
        }
    }
}

$valor1 = pegar_valor_coluna(__DIR__ . '/Trabalhos.csv', 2, 6);
$valor2 = pegar_valor_coluna(__DIR__ . '/produtividade do trabalho.csv', 2, 9);
$valor3 = pegar_valor_coluna(__DIR__ . '/inatividade do trabalho.csv', 2, 0);

$total = $valor1 * $valor2 * $valor3;
```

Comment: Sim, deu o mesmo erro. Ai alteirei o "foo" para "1" e fez a multiplicação perfeitamente. Então, o que devo fazer?! Porque são esses valores 
1.074,00
60,00
2091832

que ele pega dos arquivos csv. Será que não está aceitando por causa das vírgulas e pontos?!

Comment: Opa, espera. O erro que dá é esse aqui: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in, não é o mesmo. Perdão.

Comment: @Alex_Alex_Alex em MAQUINA valores como espaços e virgulas **não** são valores numericos, para operações matematicas somente INT e Float são funcionais.

Comment: Então vou transformar os valores em float, entendi. Vai resolver meu problema. Obrigado Guilherme!

Comment: @Alex_Alex_Alex eu adicionei um exemplo para converter para numero na resposta, testa ela por favor, tinha um bug no exemplo anterior