# Resultado com formatação incorreta

Tags: php, formatação

Estou com a seguinte dificuldade:

O cálculo está fazendo certo!

`R$ 0.01986` quando o correto seria `R$ 19.86`

Como faço para formatar esse resultado?
Codigo do resultado:

```
<span style="font-size: 12px">Custo (/Sc):<b> 
<?php $g  = round ($c/$result->valorsc,5)?>
<?php echo $g?>
```

Comment: Se o resultado é 0.01986 quando deveria ser 19.86, o cálculo não me parece certo. O que exatamente está tentando fazer?

Comment: vou explicar para vc :

Comment: o valor total acima é R$ 1.390,76 / 70 é igual R$ 19.86 o resultado ta certo, o problema é q ta aparecendo R$ 0.01986 o que vc acha que pode estar errado ?

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa, corrija o código na pergunta, por favor.

Comment: feito a alteração amigo , me ajuda por gentileza, será que é formatação pq o calculo ta certo :(

Comment: Fabio, você precisará ser mais claro em quais são os valores das variáveis, mas já adianto que provavelmente o problema está na formatação do número. O PHP usa o formato americano, reconhecendo o ponto como separador decimal; isto é, `1.390`, no PHP, é *um vírgula 390*, não *mil e 390*, como esperado.

Comment: Quais os valores das variáveis `$c` e `$result->valorsc`? O problema esta nelas. Use `var_dump($c, $result->valorsc);` pra pegar tais valores e informa pra nós.

Comment: a variavel $c = $result->valorTotal/$result->area_id os valores vem do banco de dados ai esse resultado é R$ 1.390,76 onde ele vai ser divido por pela variavel valorsc do banco de dados que é R$ 70. e o resultado da 0.01986 onde seria o correto R$ 19.86

Comment: @FabioBarroso o problema é o formato dos numeros, vocë esta tentando calcular algo que não é numero, veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/230964/3635

Comment: guilerme me ajuda kkkk ainda sou iniciante , aquele ta muito hard kkkkkk

Comment: @FabioBarroso editei a resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245422/3635

Comment: isso ocorre pq o php vai pegar uma parte dessa string q possa ser interpretada como numero, ou seja, 1.390,76/70 para o php é 1.39/70 q vai dar 0.01986

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente o seu nivel de log de erro não está exibindo Warnings e/ou Notices, mas se estivesse habilitado talvez iria exibir esta notificação no meio da página:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in ... on line 34

Você tem que entender que uma coisa é um numero, mesmo que sendo string, o formato dela tem que ser um numero que **a máquina entenda**.

Por exemplo, se fizer isto:

```
<?php

$valor1 = '100foo';
$valor2 = '2';

$total = $valor1 / $valor2;

var_dump($total);
```

Me é retornado isto:

> ```
> PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\Users\guilherme\foo.php on line 6
> int(50)
> ```

Veja que conseguiu até dividir 100 por 2 = `int(50)`, isto porque o PHP tenta fazer o "parse" da string, mas se fizer algo mais complicado como:

```
<?php

$valor1 = '100.000,00';
$valor2 = '2';

$total = $valor1 / $valor2;

var_dump($total);
```

Vai retornar isto:

> ```
> PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\Users\guilherme\Desktop\debug.php on line 7
> float(50)
> ```

O resultado que o PHP tentou fazer o "parse" e exibiu, mas só reconheceu o `100.000`, que é "praticamente" a mesma coisa `100.0`, ou seja um tipo `float`, e dividiu isto assim `100.0/2` = `float(50)`

Ou seja, `100.000,00` para **a maquina** (independente de qualquer linguagem) não é um numero, ele é apenas uma `string`, em outras linguagens fora o PHP (que tenta fazer o parse) é capaz de ocorrer *exception* ou *erros fatais* quando tentar algo como `"100.000,00"/5`

---

### Como transformar formato de dinheiro em um numero?

Primeiro eu realmente recomendo que ao invés de usar `VARCHAR` ou `CHAR` em seu banco você prefira usar `DECIMAL` e trabalhar com numeros reais, porque se o seu banco esta retornando algo como isto `100.000,00` é porque concerteza é um tipo de `CHAR` que ele usa, por favor **não use** algo como:

```
ALTER TABLE `minha_tabela` MODIFY `minha_culuna` DECIMAL(8,2)
```

Antes de mudar os valores de cada uma das linhas, se fizer isto sem mudar pode ter certeza que irá quebrar todos os dados, o que será impossível reverter, primeiro converta as linhas existentes, por exemplo `100.000,00` deve virar `100000.00, manualmente ou com um *script* que percorra todas as linhas da tabela.

Agora se você quer realmente insistir em usar `CHAR` (`VARCHAR` ou `TEXT`) então **paliativamente** você pode experimentar usar função assim:

```
function reverse_number_format($str)
{
     if (is_numeric($str)) {
        return $str;
     } elseif (preg_match('#^(.*?)[.,\s](\d{2})$#', $str, $out)) {
        return preg_replace('#\D#', '', $out[1]) . '.' . $out[2];
     }

     return false;
}
```

E então use assim no seu script:

```
round(reverse_number_format($c) / reverse_number_format($result->valorsc), 5);
```

> **Nota:** mas como eu disse, isso é uma solução **paliativa**, o recomendado é mudar a sua estrutura.

Comment: Resolvido por Guilherme Nascimento!!! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @FabioBarroso poderia marcar a resposta como correta? Se não sabe como fazer veja se isto ajuda: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635)

Answer (score 0):

1.390,76 não é um numero que se possa utilizar em cálculos matemáticos. Você não digita isso na sua maquina de calcular física ou virtual para realizar um calculo. Você digitaria 1390.76

Em programação também vale a mesma regra, os números devem ser do tipo inteiro ou, parte inteira separada por ponto seguida da parte fracionaria, `parteinteira.partefracionaria` ou por exemplo do tipo `271e+139`

No PHP a conversão de string para numero depende do formato da string, assim o PHP avalia o formato da string e caso não possua nenhum valor numérico será convertido para 0(zero). Caso possua valor numérico **em sua primeira posição** o valor será considerado e caso o valor não seja na primeira posição será desconsiderado.

Exemplos:

```
$string = (int) 'Muitas casas';

var_dump( $string ); // int(0)

$string2 = (int) '10 casas aproximadamente';

var_dump( $string2 ); // int(10)

$string3 = (int) 'Exatamente 10 casas';

var_dump( $string3 ); // int(0)
```

[Veja no ideone  o codigo abaixo completo executado](https://ideone.com/JdWwNO)

**Errado**

```
$numerador = '1.390,76';
var_dump( $numerador ); //string(8) "1.390,76"

$divisor = '70'; //string(2) "70"
var_dump( $divisor );

echo ($numerador /$divisor); // 1.39/70
```

**Uma solução**

```
//tratando string para formato válido para calculos matematicos
$numerador = '1.390,76';

//retira os pontos (.)
$numerador=str_replace(".","",$numerador);

//transforma virgula (,) em ponto (.)
$numerador=str_replace(",",".",$numerador);

var_dump( $numerador ); string(7) "1390.76" 

$divisao = ($numerador/$divisor);

//formatando para 2 casas decimais
echo number_format($divisao, 2, ',', '.');
```